# String.Substring behavior when moving a string frame k char places

Tags: c#, string, frame

Inside a For loop I do not understand following behavior of `string.Substring(i,j)`

having the code

```
String line = "TTACCTTAAC";
int k = 3; //this is variable but for simplicity is 3
String _pattern = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= line.Length - k; i++) {
    _pattern = line.Substring(i, i + k );
    //do something...
}
```

I am expecting the loop to walk over string Line (`TACCTTAAC`) `(from 0 to 10-3 = 7)`like:

```
TTA
ACC
CCT
CTT
TTA
TAA
AAC
```

However I get

```
TTA
ACCT
etc...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second parameter of `Substring` is `length`, not `end`, so you should just pass `k` instead of doing your math:

```
String line = "TTACCTTAAC";
int k = 3; //this is variable but for simplicity is 3
String _pattern = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= line.Length - k; i++) {
    _pattern = line.Substring(i, k);
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: (For OP): also 'length' would be a better variable name than k.

Comment: One doubt, in Java you can use `line.Substring(i, i + k )` so, you would not need to sum your current index to second parameter right?

Comment: Know nothing about Java, can't answer that.

Comment: @cMinor if this is your answer then select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

substring function in c# is used as  string.Substring(int startindex, int Length)

so you should use

```
_pattern = line.Substring(i, k);
```